# Does layer size matter in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, layers

Since GIMP allows to new layers to differ in size from the canvas size, does it matter? Whether a layer of different size from the canvas has uses or hinders.

Comment: What's your real question here?

Comment: @ZachSaucier: If the new one doesn't do, I can't explain any better.

Comment: It's still a bit broad...

Comment: @ZachSaucier, yeah, I figured that before I posted. I may be a noob and bad at any kind of graphics but even I could figure that.

Comment: Can you formulate your question a little bit better? Maybe you should also take a look at the Help Center http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help or take the 2-minute tour http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Not only in gimp but other programs aswell becouse at the end you need an output file in a flat format (like a png or jpg).

One layer could be a little plane and the background a big sky. Of course the layer of the plane has one size, but the important thing is the whole scene.

You can also have some floating images outside the artboard. You can use that space fo place some temporary elements, but at the end they must be croped when exporting the final image.

Comment: Interesting, but wouldn't a layer the same size as the canvas be easier to use even if you'd have something small in that layer dedicated for something small ? My noob's understanding says the RAM/workfile savings wouldn't be worth it in most cases, and you'd need to trim the layer to contain as few extra pixels as possible -after- you've made the little object.

Comment: It seems GIMP doesn't show layers of different size from canvas as different in the previews.

Comment: answer, please.

Comment: I do not like the idea of a small object on a big transparent layer. Positioning and scaling would be a pain to handle. I really do not know about ram or saving performance.

Comment: Also, if you have a big transparent layer, you can not select easily the objects below.

Answer (score 0):

If you look out at the Introduction section of the GIMP main web-site. 
Also try looking out how to change the canvas size just like in photosop
https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-image-combining.html
[image: Read This Section]

Thank You for question.